# How to decrease webSocket data flow in play framework 2.5.x

Tags: playframework, websocket, gzip

I'm developing a browser game.

The server side is written on Play Framework 2.5.x (scala). The client (JS application) communicates with server througn a websocket. Server sends to client messages every 250msec approx.

**The issue is that traffic is near 16kB/sec per player and I would like to reduce it as much as possble.**

Every message is a serialized game state around the player which looks like this (actual json is bigger, this just shows the idea):

```
{
"gameState": {
  "player": {
    "id": 218,
    "body": [[42, 20],[42, 21],[43, 21],[43, 20]],
    "name": "player",
    "color": 1,
    "isBot": false
  },
  "food": [[25, 25],[24, 25],[24, 24],[24, 23],[23, 23]],
  "enemies": [{
    "id": 217,
    "body": [[53, 46],[53, 47],[53, 48],[53, 49]],
    "name": "roBot#217",
    "color": 22,
    "isBot": true
    }]
  }
}
```

I read a couple of articles and think that I have to compress the messages  sent to client. So, I tried to filter all responses by gzip in play applicaton:

```
@Singleton
class Filters @Inject() (gzipFilter: GzipFilter, implicit val materializer: Materializer)
extends DefaultHttpFilters(gzipFilter) {
  new GzipFilter(shouldGzip = (request, response) => {
response.header.headers.get("Content-Type").exists(_.startsWith("application/json"))
  })
}
```

But this filter doesn't work. Server still sends data not compressed. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You can also think of different strategies to reduce traffic: send shorter json (reduce fields name), send a diff instead of the full state, use another format than json (protobuf)

Comment: I'm going to refactor JSON to make it as short as possible. But according to my calculations it would save me ~2kB/sec. I'll keep you in touch.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add [all settings](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/GzipEncoding) for enabling gzip filter?

I do not see that you mention this two points:

1) Add the Play filters project to your `libraryDependencies` in `build.sbt`:

```
libraryDependencies += filters
```

2) The `Filters` class can either be in the root package, or if it has another name or is in another package, needs to be configured using `play.http.filters` in `application.conf`:

```
play.http.filters = "filters.MyFilters"
```

And try to remove `@Singleton` from the `Filter` - this annotation is absent in the filter documentation, and I do not use it as well in my projects.

Comment: The library dependencies look like this:  
`libraryDependencies ++= Seq(`
`jdbc,`
`cache,`
`ws,`
`"org.scalatestplus.play" %% "scalatestplus-play" % "1.5.1" % Test,`
`filters`
`)`

`Filters` class is in a root package.

I removed `@Singleton` annotation. Filter still doesn't work.